# Backgroud Color for Divs not Showing Up in React List Items

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am refreshing on React and am working on creating new divs with random colors when I push a button. So far, I have been able to get the divs to appear when I push the button but they are not being assigned a background color. I am using a function 'randomgRgb' to generate a random color and put into an array in the state of the component. I then am mapping the array and using the random color to create my background to the div.

What am I missing?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, } from 'react';


const ColorScreen = (props) => {
    const [colors, setColors] = useState([])
    console.log(colors);

    const colorDivs = colors.map((color,i) => 
    <li key ={i}><div  style={{height:100, width:100, backgroundColor:{color} }}></div></li>
    
    )
 
    return (
        
            <div>
            <div style={{height:100, width:100, backgroundColor: randomRGb() }}></div>
            <button onClick={() => 
                setColors([...colors, randomRGb()])
            }> Add a Color</button> 
            <ul>{colorDivs}</ul>
            </div>  
        
    )
            
}

const randomRGb = ()  => {
    const red = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    const green = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
    const blue = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);

    return `rgb(${red},${green},${blue})`
}

export default ColorScreen;
```

Comment: It should be `backgroundColor:color` not `backgroundColor:{color}`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Now I am wondering why. If I were to put that color into a <li>, I would have to use a jsx element

Answer (score 1):

It should be backgroundColor:color and not backgroundColor: {color}

Thanks yousoumar

Comment: Yes, OP created new object by accident

Answer (score 0):

in this statement just remove the curlies around color and it works fine.

```
<li key ={i}><div  style={{height:100, width:100, backgroundColor:{color} }}></div></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets in `backgroundColor: {color}`. It should be `backgroundColor: color`